# Replace NA with 0 in a data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe, na

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Set NA to 0 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139284/set-na-to-0-in-r)

I have a data.frame with a column having `NA` values. I want to replace `NA` with `0` or any other value. I have tried a lot of threads and methods but it did not give me the result. I have tried the below methods.

```
a$x[a$x == NA] <- 0;
a[ , c("x")] <- apply(a[ , c("x")], 1, function(z){replace(z, is.na(z), 0)});
a$x[is.na(a$x), ] <- 0;
```

None of the above methods replaced `NA` with 0 in column `x` for data.frame `a`. Why?

Comment: Do you want to replace `NA` with `0` in all columns, or just column `x`?

Comment: @mrdwab:   just column x

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Since nobody so far felt fit to point out *why* what you're trying doesn't work:

1. `NA == NA` doesn't return `TRUE`, it returns `NA` (since comparing to undefined values should yield an undefined result).
2. You're trying to call `apply` on an atomic vector. You can't use `apply` to loop over the elements in a column.
3. Your subscripts are off - you're trying to give two indices into `a$x`, which is just the column (an atomic vector).

I'd fix up 3. to get to `a$x[is.na(a$x)] <- 0`

Comment: excellent explaination ..

Answer (score 15):

First, here's some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(one = rnorm(15),
                 two = sample(LETTERS, 15),
                 three = rnorm(15),
                 four = runif(15))
dat <- data.frame(lapply(dat, function(x) { x[sample(15, 5)] <- NA; x }))
head(dat)
#          one  two       three      four
# 1         NA    M  0.80418951 0.8921983
# 2  0.1836433    O -0.05710677        NA
# 3 -0.8356286    L  0.50360797 0.3899895
# 4         NA    E          NA        NA
# 5  0.3295078    S          NA 0.9606180
# 6 -0.8204684 <NA> -1.28459935 0.4346595
```

Here's our replacement:

```
dat[["four"]][is.na(dat[["four"]])] <- 0
head(dat)
#          one  two       three      four
# 1         NA    M  0.80418951 0.8921983
# 2  0.1836433    O -0.05710677 0.0000000
# 3 -0.8356286    L  0.50360797 0.3899895
# 4         NA    E          NA 0.0000000
# 5  0.3295078    S          NA 0.9606180
# 6 -0.8204684 <NA> -1.28459935 0.4346595
```

Alternatively, you can, of course, write `dat$four[is.na(dat$four)] <- 0`

Comment: this thing worked.thanks a lot. Could you please suggest if I did sth wrong in the above methods I tried.

Comment: isn't your 'alternatively' solution much better just for its simplicity? Does the use of two double brackets offer any advantage?

Comment: @MikePalmice, sure. The "alternatively" solution is going to be problematic if you're trying to approach the problem programmatically (for example, within a function).