# Adding a variable value to a specific record in R

Tags: r, variables, record

I am working with a large data frame (see example below), where a value is missing in the year variable. I assume that the missing value is 2000 and i would like to add it. I don't like the idea to add the value by hand, is there any other possibility?

```
    dataID dataOrigin year breedSummary breedFCI SNP sex age postcode 
1 H00-0012  IVPZ-APPX 2000         1018        3   7   1  12     7000           
4 H00-0022  IVPZ-APPX NA           1217        1   5   3   9     7514
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Please see this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172711/replace-na-values-from-a-column-with-0-in-data-frame-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data$year[which (data$dataID == 'H00-0022’)]<- 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column `dataID` has unique variables, this can be done simply with:

```
data[data$dataID == 'H00-0022',]$year = 2000
```