# R function to modify a specific column (set NA to zero)

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to set the NA values to zero for a specific column. I followed the [instructions from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172711/replace-na-values-from-a-column-with-0-in-data-frame-r), and the solution works at the R prompt.

However, it does not work when I place the commands in a function.

Here is an example:

```
d <- data.frame(colA=c("Joe", "Jane", "Jack"), colB=c(25, NA, 35), colC=c(100, 200, NA))
d
#   colA colB colC
# 1  Joe   25  100
# 2 Jane   NA  200
# 3 Jack   35   NA
```

I want to remove the NA in colB, so I followed another StackOverflow post to produce this working command: `d$colB[is.na(d$colB)] <- 0`

But now I want to write a function so that I don't have to type the column name twice, so the column is passed as an argument.

```
setNAToValue <- function(column, value) {
  column[is.na(column)] <- value
}
```

However, when I apply it, nothing happens:

```
setNAToValue(d$colB, 0)
d
#   colA colB colC
# 1  Joe   25  100
# 2 Jane   NA  200
# 3 Jack   35   NA
```

Now, when I change the `<-` to `<<-` (following the instructions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969852/update-data-frame-via-function-doesnt-work)), I get an error:

```
setNAToValue(d$colB, 0)
# Error in column[is.na(column)] <<- value : object 'column' not found
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: You probably want to not do that in a function. Functions are generally self-contained, with inputs, outputs and no side effects (like modifying things outside). If you really want a function install data.table and do `setColNAToValue = function(colname, value, data=d) set(data, i = which(is.na(d[[colname]])), j=colname, v=value)`

Comment: `d$colB` will be passed in to the function as an object, not as a reference to a column in `df`. You need to pass in both the `df` and `"b"` and then do the replacement and then return all of `df`

Comment: you seem to be rewriting the `replace` function `replace(d, col(d) == 2 & is.na(d), 0)`

Comment: @thelatemail: How do I concatenate `df` and `"b"` to form a reference to the column `df$b`?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 - something like `f <- function(data,col) {data[col][is.na(data[col])] <- 0; data}` and then called with `d <- f(d,"colB")` - square brackets `[` almost always for interactive function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing an R replacement function:

```
"setNA<-" <- function(x, value) ifelse(is.na(x), value, x)

# test using d from question
setNA(d$colB) <- 0
```

Now we have:

```
> d
  colA colB colC
1  Joe   25  100
2 Jane    0  200
3 Jack   35   NA
```

Comment: Neat, but wouldn't `"setNA<-" <- function(x, value) {x[is.na(x)] <- value; x}` be preferable in terms of only running one comparison/replacement? It's much faster generally `x <- 1:1e6; system.time(ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)); system.time({x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x})`

Comment: It might be a bit faster -- you would have to test it.  In that case you could use `replace(x, is.na(x), value)` to reduce the body to a single statement; however, `ifelse` is pretty clear and that might be the overriding consideration rather than speed.