# Set 0 to NA in R

Tags: r, na

Opposite to [Set NA to 0 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139284/set-na-to-0-in-r), I have a data.frame `data` with columns A and B (and other) in which NAs were replaced by 0 by 
`rowSums(data[,c("A", "B")], na.rm=TRUE)`.

I need to re-replace all 0 values by `NA`. As I am working with a data.frame  containing not only numeric values, [convert all zeros of a matrix in R to NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178350/convert-all-zeros-of-a-matrix-in-r-to-na) doesn't work for me (converting into a matrix doesn't seem promising here).

I tried 
`data["A" == 0] <- NA` and `data["B" == 0] <- NA` - however, it doesn't do anything (the data.frame seems to stay unchanged)

Comment: Try `"A" == 0` outside of the brackets to see why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(0, 3, "bla"), B=c("A", 0, "X"), C=c("x","B", 4)) #some fake data
df[df == 0] <- NA
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment!

I edited my post - I do not want to change ALL 0-values in the data.frame to NA, but only those in rows A and B.

Comment: Then please post an example of your data, e.g. using the `dput` function,

Comment: sorry - I also edited my reply. I think, the problem is that I want to adress specific columns.

Comment: I tried ``data$A[data$A == 0] <- NA`` and it worked. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

dplyr solution: `data %>% dplyr::mutate(A = ifelse(A == 0, NA, A))`

Answer (score 0):

Another `dplyr` solution. This uses `mutate_if` to only replace zeros with NA's if a column is numeric. B doesn't change because it is a factor/character column.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(A=rep(0:3, 5), B=rep(c("0", "1"), 10), C=c(sample(0:5, 20, replace = TRUE)))

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(ifelse(. == 0, NA, .)))
```

You can also use `mutate_all` if you wish to convert all columns (including facter/character columns):

```
df %>%
  mutate_all(funs(ifelse(. == 0, NA, .)))
```

Result:

```
    A  B  C
1  NA NA  1
2   1  2  4
3   2 NA  2
4   3  2  5
5  NA NA  5
6   1  2 NA
7   2 NA  3
8   3  2  5
9  NA NA  3
10  1  2  2
11  2 NA  5
12  3  2  2
13 NA NA  4
14  1  2  3
15  2 NA NA
16  3  2  5
17 NA NA  1
18  1  2 NA
19  2 NA  1
20  3  2  5
```

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% replace(.==0, NA)
```

base R solution

```
replace(mtcars, mtcars==0, NA)
```