# Calculating mean, se and sd over total number rather than observed

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the mean, sd and se of the frequency of several species over the number sites per habitat. I have three sites per habitat and four habitat types, so twelve sites in total. My dataset looks like this

```
Site Species Habitat  Count

A      X   Wetland      3
B      T   Urban       12
B      U   Forest      18
C      Z   Grassland    3
C      Z   Grassland    6
```

My issue is, not all species are recorded in each site and I am getting NA values when I run the code and the mean is not calculating correctly because not all species were recorded in each site (N)

```
cdata <- ddply(df, c("Species", "Habitat"), summarise,
               N    = sum(Count),
               mean = mean(Count),
               sd   = sd(Count),
               se   = sd / sqrt(N))
```

I have tried using mutate rather than summarise to set N to 3, the number of sites per habitat but I am still getting NA value for SD and SE

Comment: Were the species not present in the sites, or were they simply not recorded? If the latter, then you're trying to treat missing data as zero, which is not appropriate.

Comment: Species were not present in the site

Comment: So what is your desired result? Zeros for those missing species per site. Can you post enough data to show multiple entries per species per site?

Comment: If they weren't present, just record them as zeros, or use something like [complete](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html) or `dplyr::replace_na`.

Answer (score 0):

A work around could be to set the `NA` Values to `0`s. 
This is explained here: [Set NA to 0 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139284/set-na-to-0-in-r)

`cdata.data[is.na(cdata.data)] <- 0`

Possibly not the cleanest but seems like it may work.

Comment: `NA` is not the same as zero which can affect aggregates like `mean` and `sd`.

Comment: Agreed. I just read it as no record was equivelent to measuring the absense of somthing in which case zeros would make sense.