# Change NA in a factor

Tags: r, na

So I have data as such.

```
d <- structure(c(NA, 1L, 1L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("[1,8]", 
"(8,29]", "(29,105]", "(105,738]"), class = "factor")
```

So I want to change all NA's to `0` and then plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = data.frame(var = d)) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = d), fill = "cornflowerblue")
```

However I try with the following and it doesn't work...

```
d <- ifelse(is.na(d) == FALSE, "0", d)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set NA to 0 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139284/set-na-to-0-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
levels(d) = append(levels(d), 0)
d[is.na(d)] = 0
ggplot(data = data.frame(var = d)) + geom_bar(aes(x=d), fill="cornflowerblue")
```

[image]

Comment: excelent! But how would i now put 0 in the front?

Comment: Thats not exactly correct, that just changed the labels not the data

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will delete my previous comment. Then I don't know the answer, for now.

Answer (score 1):

there's a couple of issues:

`is.na(d) == FALSE` is not required, to negate you can use `!is.na(d)` but since you want to convert NA's you would not want to negate it

secondly you have some issues there because factors are being mixed with other stuff.

you can remove the factors by

```
d <- levels(d)[d]
```

then you can remove NAs with

```
d <- ifelse(is.na(d), "0", d)
```

finally if you do need the variable to be a factor you can do:

```
d <- factor(d, ordered = TRUE, levels = c("0", "[1,8]", "(8,29]", "(29,105]", "(105,738]"))
```

the optional parameter levels was used to prevent some of the levels (that had no records) to be lost

Answer (score 1):

A `base` solution with `addNA()`

```
d <- `levels<-`(addNA(d), c(levels(d), "0"))

#  [1] 0   [1,8]   [1,8]   (105,738]   0   0   0   [1,8]   (105,738]   [1,8]    
# Levels: [1,8] (8,29] (29,105] (105,738] 0
```

or using the `forcats` package

```
d <- forcats::fct_explicit_na(d, "0")

#  [1] 0   [1,8]   [1,8]   (105,738]   0   0   0   [1,8]   (105,738]   [1,8]    
# Levels: [1,8] (8,29] (29,105] (105,738] 0
```

Then plot again

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(var = d)) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = var), fill = "cornflowerblue")
```

[image]

---

According to your comment, you can put `"0"` in the front by this way

(`forcats::fct_relevel()` is more flexible than `stats::relevel()`)

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(var = relevel(d, "0"))) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = var), fill = "cornflowerblue")
```

[image]